# Desktop shortcut disappear

Tags: shortcuts, filelink

I've created a desktop shortcut for Eclipse by creating a .desktop file in my desktop with the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/home/blesson/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/blesson/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
```

However after rebooting my Ubuntu 15.04 the link has disappeared and I got a system error. Did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What error did you get? Provide the text of the error or an image, or both

Comment: @StarOS sadly I don't know. I got a window when starting Ubuntu (after having logged in) saying "Critical system error" with the option to report the error (I guess to Canonical) and nothing else.

Comment: Is there some button to show more details?

Comment: @StarOS no, just "report" or "cancel". Anyway now I solved the problem by creating a shortcut in "windows style" using the right click button and everything seems to work normally. I hope I've not messed something up.

Comment: If you follow that error box, choosing `report` you will come to screen where you can choose `details` before sending it, it will tell you what program crashed and why.

Comment: If you look into the folder `~/Desktop`  (or the equivalent in your language), is the file visible? If you press Ctrl+H? (unlikely, but maybe you accidentally named it `.something`).

Comment: No it isn't among the hidden files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has no relate to what have you done before in your shortcut. Instead this may happen for the system and this message box to inform you whether you want to report the error to Canonical or not.

This is related to a daemon called apport which is responsible for sending those errors. If you want to get rid of this message for future you disable it.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/apport/
```

Then change `enabled` value to 0 instead of 1. so the daemon will be disabled in later reboot.

Now you can also stop it for this session using `service`:

```
sudo service apport stop
```